# Can't read file in ItemAdding event receiver

Tags: file, sharepoint-2010

I try to read file in ItemAdding (SharePoint2010).
I use this code:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 string file = Path.Combine(properties.WebUrl, properties.AfterUrl);
 doc.Load(file);
}
```

but program return error in `doc.Load(file);` - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which user-context is the code running? does it have enough permissions to that file?

You could try using elevated privileges http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx